# Finding how many are above standard dev

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, min, iterable

Now, I want to calculate how many days of sales were above 1 std dev of the average value. How can I approach such a problem?

```
average_value= input("What is the average value of sales a day?\n")
std_dev= input("What is the standard deviation of sales a day?\n")
days= input("How many days do you want to simulate?\n")

sales=[random.gauss(average_value,std_dev) for i in range(days)]
```

Comment: What do you expect `min(x)` and `max(x)` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take the `max` or `min` of an `int`, which `x` is. You need to make a list.

```
import random

days = 10
average_value = 5.0
std_dev = 1.0

values = [random.gauss(average_value, std_dev) for i in range(days)]

>>> values
[4.610687715224258, 6.322701044169396, 4.584676199460875, 4.6351867518251595, 4.368399817684789, 4.201682562256684, 5.5211434405667354, 5.744873752293046, 4.885975367514446, 4.7502049666640405]

>>> min(values)
4.201682562256684

>>> max(values)
6.322701044169396
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Now if I wanted to find a way to determine how many of the values were 1 standard deviation above the average, how can I do that in a program? I do know the math behind it but I don't know how I can check every single value out of a list and check it to see if it is indeed above.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), `min` and `max` take an iterable, not an `int`, like you have. If you wanted to find the min and max of the values that you're getting from your loop, you'll want to store them into a list and then call the `min` and `max` functions on that created list.

Comment: `numbers = []` to create a list, then, in your loop, you will need to call `numbers.append()` to add your value to the list. You can find [more information here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure days is an integer

```
days = int(days)
```

Comment: That is not the problem at all. The issue is taking `min(x)` and `max(x)`. Turning `days` to an `int` will literally solve nothing.